# Adding Values to Buttons and Get the Sum

Tags: c#

I just wanted to add 4 values (100,200,300,400) for 4 buttons and display that in a list and get the total by pressing a another button

[Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKS0C.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give us an example?

Comment: When I click on the button that matches the values, they should fall into the list. Then the sum of the values ​​in that list should come by clicking the Total button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you have got four buttons where each of them has some value as text (100, 200, 300, 400), right? If any of them is clicked the value of the button is added to the list view.
Once the "sum" button is clicked all values from the list are summed and the total value is displayed.

First of all you need to create an event for each button click and add it's Text to the list.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       **yourList**.Items.Add(button1.Text);
    }
```

Then for the "SUM" button action you need to add all **yourList** values and display

```
    private void sumButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {                
            //make sure the text is a number
            if (int.TryParse(item.Text, out int result))
            {
                sum += result;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function in button_click

```
public int Sum(){
    int num1 = int.Parse(button1.Text);
    int num2 = int.Parse(button2.Text);
    int num3 = int.Parse(button3.Text);
    int num4 = int.Parse(button4.Text);

    int sum = num1+num2+num3+num4;
    return sum;
}
```